# glm poisson regression - regressors selection

Tags: feature-selection, model-selection, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, stepwise-regression

I have fit a GLM poisson regression model. Then i detected overdispersion, which was the reason that I have decided to fit a Negative Binomial model:

```
  # oversidpersion check
  dispersiontest(poismodel, trafo = 0)
  dispersiontest(poismodel.t, trafo = 0)
  # there is evidence of overdispersion (c is estimated to be 18.13873) which speaks quite strongly 
  # against the assumption of equidispersion (i.e. c=0). 

  summary(ngbinomial)
  ngbinomial.t <-glm.nb(TOT.N ~ OPEN.L + sqrt(MONT.S) + sqrt(POLIC) + D.PARK + sqrt(SHRUB) +
                           sqrt(WAT.RES) + L.WAT.C + sqrt(L.P.ROAD) + D.WAT.COUR)
  summary(ngbinomial.t)
  # conclusion : negative binomial is great improvement over the poisson model (based on AIC)
```

I have then run a (manual) stepwise selection procedure using `add1` and `drop1`, as well as automatic selection procedure `stepAIC`.

**Is it ok to run the stepwise selection procedure on the negative binomial model? does this procedure need to be adjusted?**

(The corresponding output for my selection procedure - just the last step is included):

BACKWARD SELECTION:

```
> nbmodel <- glm.nb(TOT.N ~ OPEN.L + sqrt(MONT.S) + sqrt(POLIC) + D.PARK + 
+                       sqrt(SHRUB) + L.WAT.C + sqrt(L.P.ROAD) + D.WAT.COUR)
> back <- stepAIC(nbmodel, direction = "backward")
Start:  AIC=386.94
TOT.N ~ OPEN.L + sqrt(MONT.S) + sqrt(POLIC) + D.PARK + sqrt(SHRUB) + 
    L.WAT.C + sqrt(L.P.ROAD) + D.WAT.COUR
Step:  AIC=381.54
TOT.N ~ OPEN.L + D.PARK + L.WAT.C + sqrt(L.P.ROAD)

                 Df    AIC
<none>              381.54
- sqrt(L.P.ROAD)  1 382.25
- L.WAT.C         1 383.42
- OPEN.L          1 390.82
- D.PARK          1 443.91
```

BACKWARD + FORWARD SELECTION:

```
> both <- stepAIC(nbmodel, direction = "both")
Start:  AIC=386.94
TOT.N ~ OPEN.L + sqrt(MONT.S) + sqrt(POLIC) + D.PARK + sqrt(SHRUB) + 
    L.WAT.C + sqrt(L.P.ROAD) + D.WAT.COUR
Step:  AIC=381.54
TOT.N ~ OPEN.L + D.PARK + L.WAT.C + sqrt(L.P.ROAD)

                 Df    AIC
<none>              381.54
+ sqrt(MONT.S)    1 382.25
- sqrt(L.P.ROAD)  1 382.25
+ sqrt(POLIC)     1 383.04
+ D.WAT.COUR      1 383.38
- L.WAT.C         1 383.42
+ sqrt(SHRUB)     1 383.50
- OPEN.L          1 390.82
- D.PARK          1 443.91
```

**Or would you advice me to first run the selection procedure on the poisson model and then fit a negative binomial model on the already reduced poisson model ?**

Answer (score 3):

You should not do stepwise regression or any similar approaches whether based on p-values or AIC or anything else (most certainly not without adjusting the final inferences for it), see e.g. [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection). Whether you are looking at a Poisson or a negatie binomial model does not affect this answer, at all.

Approaches like LASSO/elastic net (with cross-validation) or Bayesian shrinkage priors (e.g. the horseshoe, easily available e.g. in rstanarm) are generally preferrable.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. What is the reasoning behind not using approaches based on p-values or AIC?

Comment: See the link or for a more in depth discussion a textbook like Frank Harrell's Regression Modelling Strategies. In short selecting models by these ignores model uncertainty and gives really poor behaviour on new data.